# WebAssembly example forces browser to quit

Tags: c, webassembly

I'm running a WebAssembly example with Emscripten that prints a message. The browser opens for a second, prints the message, and then closes. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling the code with `emcc -s WASM=1 --emrun -o hello.html hello.c`. When I launch a server with `emrun hello.html`, the browser closes immediately after printing the output. I've tried different flags, but I can't find any way to keep the browser open. Any ideas?

Comment: Well the return statement is exiting the program don't you think ?

Comment: When I take away the return statement and return void, the browser still closes. I also get warnings about main not returning an int.

Comment: I've also tried adding an infinite loop after the `printf` statement. The browser stays open, but it won't print the message.

Comment: Clearly, and infinite loop will just block the UI, put a reading statement like gets() or scanf().

Comment: I added `getchar` and `scanf` after `printf`, and the browser (Chrome) opens a box asking for input. After I provide input, the browser prints the message and then closes. Very frustrating.

Comment: It's gonna close after the program is finished running, that's just how `emrun` works.

Comment: You should set a main loop using `emscripten_set_main_loop(...)` rather than just an infinite loop